# Why can't I rescue Tera in Dracula X Chronicles PSP?

Tags: psp, castlevania-dracula-x-chronicles

In the alternate stage 3, why can't I rescue tera?

I have gone to the first door that I came to and can't break the wall underneath.

Comment: Did you found and kept the key as subweapon in the previous stage?